# Sass extending isn't working with simple example

Tags: css, angular, sass

below is both simple sass code,an Angular 2 component accessing the sass code, and the rendered HTML. In my last span element, blueBig is not working as it should. I'm new to sass and I'm not sure why this simple example is not extending properly. Can anyone shed some light on this issue for me? Thank you!

> **Angular2 Component**

```
@Component({
selector: 'test',
template: `
    <h1> testing sass</h1>
    <span [ngClass]="{blue : true}">This should be blue</span> 
    <br>
    <span [ngClass]="{big: true}">This should be big</span>
    <br>

    <span [ngClass]="{blue : true, big: true }">This should be big and blue</span>
    <br>
    <span [ngClass]="{blueBig : true}"> this should be big and blue as well</span>

`,
styleUrls: ['assets/scss/testing-component.scss']
})
```

> **Sass**

```css
.blue{
  color:blue;
}

.big{
  font-size: 200%;
}

.blueBig{
  @extend .blue;
  @extend .big;
}
```

> **HTML**

[image: Rendered HTML]

> **Rendered HTML**

[image]

Comment: Did you try extending from a single line: `@extend .blue, .big;`?

Comment: @JonathanMichalik unfortunately, that doesn't work

Comment: It would be helpful to show the rendered HTML rather than the template.

Comment: @steveax good call, I included that as well.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled your Sass locally and it appears to be authored correctly.

Without being able to see the rendered HTML, my guess is that Angular is converting camelcase `blueBig` into kebab-case `blue-big`. Try putting quotes around the classname, i.e.

```
<span [ngClass]="{'blueBig' : true}">
```

Comment: Hmm, this did not seem to work as well. Admittedly, I'm also new to angular. Where is the rendered HTML so I can post that correctly for everyone to see?

Comment: It's what you see in the Elements panel when you open up the Developer Tools

Comment: Okay, I hope the picture I attached is correct and helps. Thanks again for trying to identify what's going on